# How do I have a web game run on the same URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-routing

For rapid prototyping of my concepts, I'm using Express with Mongo and so far have set up a mongostore cookie storage system.

My question: Is it possible, after logging in/authenticating/etc, to have everything occur on the same page, aka '/game'? I still want multiple views and routes to be rendered, but using different areas of the screen, or overwriting elements on the screen, with the base game.jade still visible.

I essentially want to have the user on the same URL the entire time, but still use multiple routes and views. I looked into stuff like '/game/:stuff' but that still changes the URL I think.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI this is called a single-page web application.

One common way to do this is to route to different views using the hash token. For example, all of the following URLs would be part of the same page:

```
/game#introScreen
/game#level1
/game#level2
```

Your client code can respond to changes in the hash portion of the URL and change the display accordingly. The page does not reload and all your JavaScript code (and variable state) remains in place.

If you're using a framework like angularjs it can help do the routing for you.

Comment: It looks like the answer is basically Angular.js. Angular-UI or UI-Router will also help. I think I have enough resources to continue the project this way, seems simpler than trying to do without angular. Now I know what they mean by the MEAN stack. Thanks!